# $\mathrm{gcd}(a+nb,b)=\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, integers

I have a question:
Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $(a+bn,b)=(a,b)$, $(a,b)$ being the greatest common divisor.

Is this a correct approach?

Let $e=(a+bn,b), \quad n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $e$ is expressible as the smallest linear combination of $an+b$ and $b$ so there exists $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
e=u(a+bn)+vb
$$
and $e$ is the smallest positive such number. Rearranging on the right hand side we get
$$
e=ua+(un+v)b
$$
which gives a linear combination of $a$ and $b$. Since $e$ is still the smallest such we get that $(a,b)=e$. If this is correct is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: No, it's not correct because nothing tell you that $e$ is the smallest $e$ with the fact that $e=ua+(un+v)b$. Notice that you can suppose WLOG that $(a,b)=1$ and make your proof that will allow you to conclude.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Proof-verification questions are rarely duplicates -- the answers to the older question may present a _different_ proof but not tell what if anything there's wrong with _this_ one.

Comment: @HenningMakholm On the other hand the question also is "is there a more elegant solution?" I think this is the crucial part of the question, which therefore, I think, is basically a duplicate. Of course, one may have a different opinion here.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound quite convincing -- when you say "since $e$ is still the smallest such" it sounds to me like you're essentially assuming what you were supposed to prove.

I suspect your strategy is to show that the integer combinations of $a+bn$ and $b$ are the same as the integer combinations of $a$ and $b$. But in order to do that without handwaving you need to show that every combination of $a+bn$ and $b$ is also a combination of $a$ and $b$, **and** that every combination of $a$ and $b$ is also a combination of $a+bn$ and $b$. Your proof as it stands only does the first half of this.

---

(An alternative which seems more direct to me would be to show that the *common divisors* of $a+bn$ and $b$ are the same as the common divisors of $a$ and $b$).

Comment: Assume that $d=(a,b)$ and $e=(a+nb,b)$, then
  $$
  d\mid a\qquad d\mid b
  $$
  and therefore
  $$
  d\mid bn
  $$
  so
  $$
  d\mid a+bn.
  $$
  We see that $d\mid e$ since $d$ divides everything $e$ divides. Looking at the second assumption we can conclude that
  $$
  e\mid b\qquad e\mid a+nb
  $$ 
  therefore
  $$
  e\mid a\qquad e\mid nb
  $$
  this gives $d\mid e$. But 
  $$
  d\mid e, e\mid d\Rightarrow d=e.
  $$

Comment: something like this?

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa: That works (I'd want a bit more detail about how you conclude $e\mid a$, though), but was not exactly what I had in mind. I imagined a proof along the lines of "assume $x$ is _some_ common divisor of $a$ and $a+nb$. Then (bla bla bla) so $x$ is also a common divisor of $a$ and $b$. And (bla bla bla) vice versa. Since being a common divisor of $a$ and $a+nb$ is the same property as being a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, the _greatest_ number with this property must be the same no matter what we call the property."

Comment: thank you!

$e\mid a$ follows from $e\mid b$ and $e\mid a+nb$ right?

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa: Yes.